# ASP.NET MVC Routing with Default Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

For a scenario, I have a ASP.NET MVC application with URLs that look like the following:

```
http://example.com/Customer/List
http://example.com/Customer/List/Page/2
http://example.com/Customer/List
http://example.com/Customer/View/8372
http://example.com/Customer/Search/foo/Page/5
```

These URLs are achieved with following routes in `Global.asax.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CustomerSearch"
    , "Customer/Search/{query}/Page/{page}"
    , new { controller = "Customer", action = "Search" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "CustomerGeneric"
    , "Customer/{action}/{id}/Page/{page}"
    , new { controller = "Customer" }
);

//-- Default Route
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

These all have gone well until a new requirement arrived and wants to drop keyword 'Customer' off the URL, to make the URLs look like:

```
http://example.com/List
http://example.com/List/Page/2
http://example.com/List
http://example.com/View/8372
http://example.com/Search/foo/Page/5
```

***Edit:*** corrected example links, thanks to @haacked.

I tried to add new `MapRoutes` to take `{action}` only and have default controller set to Customer. eg/

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CustomerFoo"
    , "{action}"
    , new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index" }
);
```

This seems to work, however now all links generated by Html.ActionLink() are weird and no longer URL friendly.

So, is this achievable? Am I approaching in the right direction?

Comment: Did you delete the old routes?

Comment: No, I had my new routes placed before the original routes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

don't mix a rule like: `"{action}/{id}"` with one that's `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` ... specially when id in the later has a default value i.e. is optional.

In that case you have nothing that allows routing to know which one is the right one to use.

A workaround, if that's what you need, would be to add a constrain (see [this](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx)) to the action in the earlier to a set of values i.e. List, View. Of course that with these types of rules, you can't have a controller with the same name of an action.

Also remember that if you specify a default action & id in the `"{action}/{id}"` rule, that will be used when you hit the route of your site.

Comment: Apologise that my reply isn't speedy, because I want to try out the answers before response with feedbacks. Sorry about this :P

Comment: @rockacola its k, there is no rush.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Route constraints will give me the customisation I desired without jeopardise MapRoute. I need to reorganise all my existing routes tho. Thanks @Freddy!

Answer (score 10):

Why does the first URL in the new list still have "Customer". I assume that's a typo and you meant:

- http://example.com/List
- http://example.com/List/Page/2
- http://example.com/List
- http://example.com/View/8372
- http://example.com/Search/foo/Page/5

The following routes work for me:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CustomerSearch"
    , "Search/{query}/Page/{page}"
    , new { controller = "Customer", action = "Search" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "CustomerGeneric"
    , "{action}/{id}/Page/{page}"
    , new { controller = "Customer" }
);

//-- Default Route
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

How are you generating your links. Since the Controller is no longer in the URL of your route (aka, you don't have "{controller}" in the route URL), but it's a default value, you need to make sure to specify the controller when generating routes.

Thus instead of

```
Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName")
```

do

```
Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", "Customer")
```

Why? Suppose you had the following routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "foo/{action}",
    new { controller = "Cool" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "bar/{action}",
    new { controller = "Neat" }
);
```

Which route did you mean when you call this?

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName") %>
```

You can differentiate by specifying the controller and we'll pick the one that has a default value that matches the specified one.

Comment: Thanks for reply Phil. The routes work fine **IF all pages are from Customer controller**. Say if I have `User` controller with `SignIn` action: /User/SignIn/ request will be hijacked by **CustomerDefault** (which is {action}/{id}) where I want it to fall into **Default** (which is {controller}/{action}). Is there a way to teach your route which parameter meant to be **action** and which meant to be **controller**? Thanks again, love your blog.

Comment: @rockacola I just added an answer about this (before seeing your comment), add a constraint to limit {action} so it doesn't use that rule for {customer}.

Comment: Use a constraint, just as Freddy said.

Answer (score 4):

You can [create a route that is constrained to only match actions in your `Customer` controller](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/09/using-default-controller-in-aspnet-mvc.html).

```
public static class RoutingExtensions {
    ///<summary>Creates a route that maps URLs without a controller to action methods in the specified controller</summary>
    ///<typeparam name="TController">The controller type to map the URLs to.</typeparam>
    public static void MapDefaultController<TController>(this RouteCollection routes) where TController : ControllerBase {
        routes.MapControllerActions<TController>(typeof(TController).Name, "{action}/{id}", new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
    ///<summary>Creates a route that only matches actions from the given controller.</summary>
    ///<typeparam name="TController">The controller type to map the URLs to.</typeparam>
    public static void MapControllerActions<TController>(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults) where TController : ControllerBase {
        var methods = typeof(TController).GetMethods()
                                         .Where(m => !m.ContainsGenericParameters)
                                         .Where(m => !m.IsDefined(typeof(ChildActionOnlyAttribute), true))
                                         .Where(m => !m.IsDefined(typeof(NonActionAttribute), true))
                                         .Where(m => !m.GetParameters().Any(p => p.IsOut || p.ParameterType.IsByRef))
                                         .Select(m => m.GetActionName());

        routes.Add(name, new Route(url, new MvcRouteHandler()) {
            Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(defaults) { { "controller", typeof(TController).Name.Replace("Controller", "") } },
            Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", new StringListConstraint(methods) } }
        });
    }

    private static string GetActionName(this MethodInfo method) {
        var attr = method.GetCustomAttribute<ActionNameAttribute>();
        if (attr != null)
            return attr.Name;
        return method.Name;
    }

    class StringListConstraint : IRouteConstraint {
        readonly HashSet<string> validValues;
        public StringListConstraint(IEnumerable<string> values) { validValues = new HashSet<string>(values, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); }

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {
            return validValues.Contains(values[parameterName]);
        }
    }

    #region GetCustomAttributes
    ///<summary>Gets a custom attribute defined on a member.</summary>
    ///<typeparam name="TAttribute">The type of attribute to return.</typeparam>
    ///<param name="provider">The object to get the attribute for.</param>
    ///<returns>The first attribute of the type defined on the member, or null if there aren't any</returns>
    public static TAttribute GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(this ICustomAttributeProvider provider) where TAttribute : Attribute {
        return provider.GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(false);
    }
    ///<summary>Gets the first custom attribute defined on a member, or null if there aren't any.</summary>
    ///<typeparam name="TAttribute">The type of attribute to return.</typeparam>
    ///<param name="provider">The object to get the attribute for.</param>
    ///<param name="inherit">Whether to look up the hierarchy chain for attributes.</param>
    ///<returns>The first attribute of the type defined on the member, or null if there aren't any</returns>
    public static TAttribute GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(this ICustomAttributeProvider provider, bool inherit) where TAttribute : Attribute {
        return provider.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>(inherit).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    ///<summary>Gets the custom attributes defined on a member.</summary>
    ///<typeparam name="TAttribute">The type of attribute to return.</typeparam>
    ///<param name="provider">The object to get the attribute for.</param>
    public static TAttribute[] GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>(this ICustomAttributeProvider provider) where TAttribute : Attribute {
        return provider.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>(false);
    }
    ///<summary>Gets the custom attributes defined on a member.</summary>
    ///<typeparam name="TAttribute">The type of attribute to return.</typeparam>
    ///<param name="provider">The object to get the attribute for.</param>
    ///<param name="inherit">Whether to look up the hierarchy chain for attributes.</param>
    public static TAttribute[] GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>(this ICustomAttributeProvider provider, bool inherit) where TAttribute : Attribute {
        if (provider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("provider");

        return (TAttribute[])provider.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), inherit);
    }
    #endregion
}
```