# How to handle Routing in mvc?

Tags: c#-4.0

How to hide Controller name, action name and show only passed parameters using Routing in MVC
for example
Url is http://www.test.com/pages/Pages/?pageURL=Returns

I want Url just :- http://www.test.com/Returns

pageURL=Returns is dynamical parameter value

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { action = "index", id = "" },
     // Register below the name of all the other controllers
     new { controller = @"^(account|support)$" });

  routes.MapRoute("home", "{action}",
     new { controller = "device", action = "index" });
}
```

Source: [How do I configure ASP.NET MVC routing to hide the controller name on a "home" page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627984/how-do-i-configure-asp-net-mvc-routing-to-hide-the-controller-name-on-a-home-p)

Comment: Controller and Action name is fixed. i want url just as same as passed parameter name,