# Add default controller to the project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am really really really new to ASP MVC and I want to add a default controller to the projcet.
I searched for this topic but none of theme helped to me like :
[ASP.NET MVC Routing with Default Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713379/asp-net-mvc-routing-with-default-controller)
and ...

How can add a default controller to the project to prevent application error?
When I browse the `http://localhost:8688/`, I see an error: **The resource cannot be found.**

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?  Normally when you create a new MVC project it creates a Home controller and creates a route in your global.asax.  Do you see these?

Comment: @MarkOreta The resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you create a new MVC based application there's a default setting in the **Global.asax.cs** file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

So the default controller would be called *HomeController* in the Controllers subfolder. and the default action would be *Index*.

Check if you have that in the Global.asax.cs and also have a HomeController class.

Likely you selected to create an empty MVC application which doesn't put a HomeController class in it and gives an error when you hit F5 (what's not there can't be executed).

Comment: Reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaalllllllllyyyyyyyyyyyyyy nice. Thanks. This is the answer :x