# Removing Action name from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a site structured like this -

- Home page - www.mysite.com.
- Categories page - www.mysite.com/Categories. (linked from Home page)

On the Categories page, I have a list of Category links.

If someone selects a Category, I want to display the URL like this -

- (after selecting CategoryA) - www.mysite.com/Categories/CategoryA
- (after selecting CategoryB) - www.mysite.com/Categories/CategoryB

*Currently*, my URLs display like this - www.mysite.com/Categories/**Index**/CategoryA

I have a `HomeController` and a `CategoriesController`. The `CategoriesController` has an `Action` called `Index`, which excepts a Category, which is where the word **Index** is coming from.

How can I get rid of the word **Index**?

I tried mapping a `Route`, like the following, but it did not work -

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CategoriesPage",
            url: "Categories/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Categories", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3628138/426422 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713379/asp-net-mvc-routing-with-default-controller

Comment: Thanks Mike! I ended up finding the answer else where. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

My solution was the following -

I mapped a `Route` like this -

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "CategoryPage",
            "Categories/{id}",
            new { controller = "Categories", action = "Index" }
        );
```

And in my `View`, my `ActionLink` looked like this -

```
@Html.ActionLink("CategoryDescription", "Index", new { controller = "Categories", id = c.Id })
```

(this answer lead me to this solution - [Routing: How to hide action name in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968689/routing-how-to-hide-action-name-in-url))

Answer (score 0):

/* This is For  Action Name Only */

       routes.MapRoute("custom_name1", "sitemap", new { controller = "home",  action = "sitemap", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
/* This is For  Controller Name Only */
      routes.MapRoute("custom_name2", "home", new { controller = "home", action = "sitemap", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

Comment: please provide more details