# asp.net mvc 5 can i hide controller name from url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

we have one project in asp.net mvc 5 when i run my project and click on some button for go to the next page then we are getting the url like 
wwww.abx.com/project/projectname .

where **project** is my controller name and **projectname** is Action name

so if i want so url like

**wwww.abx.com/projectname**

then this is possible ?

please if any one have some solution so please give it

here is my route.config file code

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "view1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes){
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
name: "ProjectName1",
url: "Projectname1",
defaults: new { controller = "Project1", action = "Projectname1" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
name: "ProjectName2",
url: "Projectname2",
defaults: new { controller = "Project2", action = "Projectname2" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
name: "ProjectName3",
url: "Projectname3",
defaults: new { controller = "Project3", action = "Projectname3" }
);



routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "view1", id = 
UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


}
```

Comment: we want for more then 5 pages.

Comment: wwww.abx.com/project/projectname1 
wwww.abx.com/project/projectname2
wwww.abx.com/project/projectname3 
wwww.abx.com/project/projectname4 
wwww.abx.com/project/projectname5

and i  want like  

wwww.abx.com/projectname1 
wwww.abx.com/projectname2
wwww.abx.com/projectname3 
wwww.abx.com/projectname4 
wwww.abx.com/projectname5

Comment: Check it please.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do this for only one controller - [add a custom route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) as suggested by @Hamed Javaheri, [or use attribute mapping as described here](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/understanding-url-rewriting-and-url-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-mvc5-with-examples)

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Project",
                url: "projectname",
                defaults: new { controller = "project", action = "projectname", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

If you want this to work for **many / most** routes then you might want to change the default mapping, somethin similar to this question:

[ASP.NET MVC Default URL View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006673/asp-net-mvc-default-url-view?rq=1) and

[ASP.NET MVC Routing with Default Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713379/asp-net-mvc-routing-with-default-controller)

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "project", id = "" }
            );
        }
```